# Variáveis no App.vue

Tags: vue.js, vue.js-2

Possuo dentro do arquivo App.vue a variável nomeCliente

```
{{nomeCliente}}
```

Estou criando uma function dentro da App.vue para preencher a variável

```
this.$eventHub.$on('mostrarNome', function(value) {
    this.nomeCliente = value;
});
```

que é chamada de dentro do Cadastro.vue

```
this.$eventHub.$emit('mostrarNome', 'Teste Cliente')
```

Minha dúvida é se existe outra forma de fazer esse preenchimento da variável sem a necessidade de criar uma função.

Comment: Neste caso em especifico, onde possivelmente você ter acesso aos dados do Usuario, eu usaria o Vuex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer, se no caso você possui um `<router-view>` no seu App.vue, e o componente que você está emitindo o evento de preenchimento do 'Teste Cliente' estiver um nível abaixo apenas, pode-se criar um evento que irá realizar o preenchimento do nome direto, sem uma função:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>--{{ nomeCliente }}--</p>
    <router-view @mostrarNome="nomeCliente = $event"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    nomeCliente: 'Meu nome'
  })
}
</script>
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="formup">
    <h1>Componente interno</h1>
    <form class="createform" @submit.prevent="evento">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">
        Enviar
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Stackoverflow',
  methods: {
    evento () {
      this.$emit('mostrarNome', 'Teste Cliente')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Detalhe que a emissão do evento pode ser em qualquer método, `watch`, etc, e não apenas com o `@submit`.

Uma outra maneira de fazer é utilizando o [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex). No caso, provavelmente você possui um objeto "cliente", onde este ao ser preenchido você armazenaria ele em uma Store e seu estado ficaria uniforme em toda a aplicação. Um exemplo simples de uma *ClientStore* seria:

**ClientStore.js**

```
import Vue from '@/bootstrap'

// state
const state = {
  client: {}
}

// getters
const getters = {
  client: state => state.client
}

// actions
const actions = {
  getClient: ({ commit, state }) => {
    return Vue.http
      .get('clients/1') // mudaria a requisição para a que você precisa
      .then(({ data }) => commit('setClientData', data))
  }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  setClientData (state, data) {
    state.client = data
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

Assim, com os dados na Store preenchidos, você acessaria em qualquer local da sua aplicação com o `this.$store.state.client` ou `this.$store.getters.client` ou pode realizar o mapeamento para client e acessar com o `this.client`:

**App2.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button type="button" @click="test">Test</button>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  computed: mapState({
    client: state => state.ClientStore.client
  }),
  methods: {
    test () {
      console.log(this.client)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Confira mais na documentação sobre como instalar/configurar o Vuex, há diversas maneiras, utilize a que considerar melhor. Se for utilizar, use junto ao [Vue Dev Tools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools), uma ferramenta excelente para trabalhar com eventos/store.